# How to group by day, plot it against the same graph and analyse it?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am currently try to plot my dataset to obtain the following image.
(Dataset : https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1K53Xn0CnidHCtJYlZW25-9Mt02MV1-rT )

[My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhGxm.png)

X axis is the timespan of a day 0 - 24hrs, and y-axis being the run speed at that duration.
I want to eventually calculate the average speed per day and analyse the trend and so forth.

I was able to plot for 1 day as shown below, using
df["2023-07-07":"2023-07-07"]['SPEED'].plot()

[Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/amhdB.png)

But if i plot it multiple times, it does overlap against the previous plot.
Instead this happened. A continuous timeseries.
[Overlap fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysXDz.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert your timestamps to the date with [`dt.normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.normalize.html) then [`groupby.mean`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.mean.html) and [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel('outputnew.xlsx')

(df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])
              .dt.normalize().rename('day'))
 ['SPEED'].mean()
 .plot()
)
```

Output:

[image]

Or using [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sns.lineplot(data=df.assign(day=pd.to_datetime(df['TIMESTAMP'])
                                  .dt.normalize()),
             x='day', y='SPEED')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the great reply.
However, how do I go about plotting multiple dates on the same graph? Like the figure i sketched out.

Comment: @Van.dBag then I misunderstood your question, you said "*I want to eventually calculate the average speed per day*". What exactly is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry for the confusing! You definitely did answer that part of the question. And i thank you for that.
However, the first component of my problem is to showcase and compare the timeseries of the speed for each day in a month, like https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhGxm.png . 
Essentially have all the speed data of each date plotted in a singular line and plotted against the x-axis (time) and y-axis (speed). Hope that makes sense! Thank you Sir.

Comment: Then add day and time columns, you will be able to use those as grouper/hue/etc. depending on the chosen method: `df.assign(day=dt.dt.normalize(), time=dt.dt.time)`